# Using Action bar style generator with holo colors generator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

To style my android application an make it more beautiful, i have used the [action bar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to create a theme and [Action holo color generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

They both give me a res folder when i extract and i want to use both of them in my application, but am not sure if thats allowed or would create some conflicts.

I would like to know how i can include both of them in my app.
Thanks

Comment: There is no 3rd party tool available for this, you have to do it manually, copy/paste all the files into the particular folder and you have to merge styles.xml into your actual project styles.xml file.

Comment: how do i edit my manifest file to use these two?

Comment: Sorry there is no ready made tool available which can you give you ready manifest file by merging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the link](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html) in Wayne May's answer suggests, you just have to make the ActionBar theme extends the Holo color's theme.

Here are the steps needed to get this to work:

1. Chose a prefix for your themes (the last part of your app's package name for example)
2. Generate and download a theme for you action bar using [ActionBarStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). Name this theme *<prefix>_ActionBar*.
3. Generate and download a theme for your widgets using [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/). Name this theme *<prefix>_Widgets*.
4. Unzip the files you downloaded in your resource folder (be careful not to overwrite anything).
5. Edit the files *values/<prefix>_actionbar_styles.xml* and *values-v14/<prefix>_actionbar_styles.xml* to replace every occurrence of `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` with `parent="@style/<prefix>_Widgets"`
6. Use `<prefix>_ActionBar` as your theme (or as your theme's parent)

Comment: I think so but it's no longer needed. Android 5 introduced Material design which basically allows you to chose a `colorPrimary` and an `colorAccent` and uses them to tint most of the UI widgets. Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html?m=1) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pretty good write up on how to do this - have a look at this: 
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.